# C# : Wrong Extension when Upload

Tags: file-upload, upload

I am having a page with Telerik Upload Control.
I want to save the file Extension in database.
I am using GetExtension() Method.
It gives me a wrong Extension when the file has '.' in the name.
Example : Micro.18-7.pdf
When i am trying to get the Extension of the file,it shows ".18-7".

please anyone help me in this to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
AGM Raja

Answer (score 0):

Create your own method like such

```
 static string GetFileExtension(string fileName)
        {
            var result = fileName.Split('.');
            return result[result.Length - 1];
        }
```